# Finding the binding energy iof methylated miRNA to an mRNA

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, chemical-biology

I'm working on a project in biophysics and I need to find if there is a difference in binding of an miRNA to an mRNA when in one case the miRNA is methylated and in the other it isn't. 
What tools should I use to calculate the binding energy in each case?
I have the binding sequence of the miRNA.

Comment: Something like free energy perturbations?

Comment: Yes, after reading about FEP in wikipedia I believe it might be what i'm looking for.